# Is there a range of Window Style or Extended Window Style values reserved for custom control usage?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am looking for the [Window Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles) or [Extended Window Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles) equivalent to the [WM_USER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-user) or [WM_APP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-app) constants and specified ranges used with window messages. I am working on an custom control library and want to define styles that will not conflict with styles used for the window itself. I understand that the binary values should be mutually exclusive to support ORing of styles. I cannot find any documentation where such a range is specified.

Comment: @HansPassant Aren't the lower 16 bits of the window style control-specific?

Comment: Since messages in the `WM_USER` range are control specific, you can define a control-specific message to set control-specific styles (see [extended list-view styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/extended-list-view-styles) for an example).

Comment: The use-case is for the control library to be used by other applications in similar ways to native win32 controls. Using GWLP_USERDATA is not a good solution as the end application could no longer use that method for application-related data.

It would be nice for the styles to be set by the application at time of window creation, but if subsequent messages are the other option, I will have to work with that.

Comment: Raymond Chen confirms the bottom 16 bits of window style flags belong to the window class. [Which window style bits belong to whom?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031203-00/?p=41633)

Comment: Also, you do not have to use `GWLP_USERDATA`. When you're registering your window classes, you can reserve per-window memory (`cbWndExtra`) and use that with `GetWindowLongPtr`/`SetWindowLongPtr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not explicitly documented on MSDN, but confirmed by Raymond Chen's blog:

[Which window style bits belong to whom?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031203-00/?p=41633):

> There are 64 bits of styles in the parameters to CreateWindowEx. Which ones belong to whom? Windows defines the meanings of the high word of the dwStyle parameter and all of the bits in the dwExStyle parameter. **The low 16 bits of the dwStyle parameter are defined by the implementor of the window class (by the person who calls RegisterClass).**

You can confirm this by looking at the defined styles of standard Win32 control classes, which have overlapping bits. For example,
`BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON` for `BUTTON`, `ES_CENTER` for `EDIT`, `SS_CENTER` for `STATIC`, etc are all defined as 0x00000001, but are all usable in the `dwStyle` parameter depending on which registered class is being created.

Raymond's blog post also says:

> If you need more than 16 bits of style information, you can design your class so additional information is passed in the lpParam parameter (the last one) to CreateWindow/Ex, which can be received from the lpCreateParams member of the CREATSTRUCT structure. Alternatively, you can set additional styles with a custom message, such as listview’s LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE message.